Unsound but consistent calculi, a simple example
Let us assume the Hilbert system $\Sigma$ but we substitute its identity axiom x = x with its negation x $\neq$ x. So we get an alternate Hilbert system $\Sigma$‘. Then $\Sigma$‘ $\vdash x \neq x$. But $\Sigma$‘ $\nvDash x \neq x$ since x $\neq$ x is just false.
My question: Would this be an example of a consistent but unsound calculus?

No. If $\vdash$ then $\vDash$. The enlarged system $\Sigma'$ includes the false axiom, thus there is no problem.
